# Opposite of "Educated Guess"?

Tags: word-usage, antonyms

What's the antonym for *educated guess*? Is it 'uninformed guess' or just 'guess'? Is there such thing as 'uneducated guess'? I couldn't use it as it only negates part of a phrase and doesn't seem opposite of 'informed/educated guess'.

Comment: I'm American and I would say "wild guess" or "shot in the dark" to both mean "I have no idea what I'm talking about but will try my best."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## wild guess

from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wild%20guess):

> **wild guess** *noun*
> **:** a guess based on no knowledge or information
> *"I have no idea how many peanuts are in the jar." "Take a wild guess."*

Comment: Other suggestions that are probably more informal include a "stab" or "wild stab"; a "shot in the dark"; a "total guess"; a "long shot" (suggests some slight knowledge)

Comment: These are great suggestions, and belong in answers of their own, rather than a comment on my answer. I particularly like "shot in the dark" and would have answered that instead if I'd thought of it

Comment: @swmcdonnell Ping! Forgot to tag you on my above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to contrast with the antonym, the answer could be different. Wild guess, as suggested above, is most excellent if you want to contrast the nature of the guess.

If, however, you wish to contrast the full concept of an educated guess, you might need to get more creative. Uneducated opinion, could work in certain circumstances, especially if you want to convey a certain cheekiness with it’s usage.

*I’ll make an educated guess, and say…*
*Well, in my uneducated opinion, that is…*

As long as the original idiom is recognizable, you can create an antonym by substituting key words in the phrase to suit your needs.